# Berkshelf having issues uploading cookbooks to Chef-Server

Tags: chef-infra, cookbook, berkshelf, chefdk

I'm trying to use `Berkshelf` to upload a cookbook with a few dependencies to my Chef-Server. When I use `chef exec berks upload` I am presented with a bunch of different errors. My current setup is using the latest, or close to, ChefDK versions using a chef_repo with the following file structure. I have multiple repos for the multipe different Orgs I'm hooked into for different Chef-Servers. I don't have anything in my `$HOME/.chef/`, or on Windows, `C:\chef\`, doesn't even exist. I'm sharing the same chef_repo between my Windows, CentOS 7 VM, and my Docker container, so that hasn't changed. The chef_repo was generated by using the `chef generate repo` command.

https://gist.github.com/predatorian3/24ba83bd7e98ac7300bf#file-chefdk_repo_setup

The contents of my knife.rb are as follows

https://gist.github.com/predatorian3/24ba83bd7e98ac7300bf#file-00-knife-rb

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong when I'm attempting to upload these cookbooks using `Berkshelf`.

On `CMD`, using `Cmder`

https://gist.github.com/predatorian3/24ba83bd7e98ac7300bf#file-chefdk_cmder_berks-rb

As you can see in this Gist, I was able to do a `chef exec knife ssl check` and it succeeded.

On `Cygwin`

https://gist.github.com/predatorian3/24ba83bd7e98ac7300bf#file-chefdk_cygwin_berks-rb

On CentOS 7,

https://gist.github.com/predatorian3/24ba83bd7e98ac7300bf#file-chefdk_centos7_berks-rb

On CentOS 7 using Docker's CentOS 7 image,

https://gist.github.com/predatorian3/24ba83bd7e98ac7300bf#file-chefdk_docker_centos7_berks-rb

Using a pure Ruby install, and the Chef RubyGem and Berkshelf gem installed, yielded the same errors, except the parts about some webagent cookie, which I suppose is good.

--EDIT 2016-02-27--

As a temporary work around, I had to use `--no-ssl-verify` in order for berks to upload the cookbooks. However, it seems to be a bug with `ridley-4.3.2`. Then berks is also not "honoring" the `ENV[SSL_CERTS_DIR]` or `ENV[SSL_CERTS_FILE]` statements in my knife.rb [There's a bug submitted for it already.](https://github.com/berkshelf/berkshelf-api-client/issues/9) I guess this bug is an outstanding bug.

Answer (score 1):

Berkshelf uses its own config parsing system which might be unable to read your `knife.rb` successfully. This isn't super likely, but some permutation of that or not looking in the right folder is probably a contributing factor. You can make this a non-issue by creating a Berkshelf [`config.json`](http://berkshelf.com/#configuring-berkshelf) with the required data.

Comment: Would I have to modify the config.json for each chef-repo I have? I have a central spot for my cookbooks, Then each chef-repo is tied to a different Chef-Server.

Comment: Yeah :-/ In theory Berkshelf should mirror Chef's own knife config loading (though with different underlying code). Can you pastebin your knife.rb? I can try to take a look if there is anything obviously at fault.

Comment: Here is my `knife.rb`. Its in my `chef-repo/.chef/` directory, and my cookbooks are in a different directory so I don't have a bunch of copies for each repo.

Comment: I don't see where you added it?

Comment: Seems fine, nothing overly complex. I would throw a pry or puts in the knife.rb so you can see what certs_loc is while it is being loaded. Might be a relative path issue?

Comment: It is loading my configuration correctly, in the correct directory.

Comment: I've updated my Gist, https://gist.github.com/predatorian3/24ba83bd7e98ac7300bf#file-berks_upload_error-rb

Comment: It's getting a different error now. Are your TLS certs self-signed?

Comment: Yes, they're generated when I install Chef-Server. I've also already ran `chef exec knife ssl fetch` and downloaded the Certs. Which allows me to perform other actions on the Chef-Server

Comment: Chef's `ssl fetch` has no effect on Berkshelf. You'll need to either disable TLS verification (very very not recommended) or handle this via old-school openssl config. Easiest option is to set the `$SSL_CERT_DIR` to point at the trusted certs dir while using Berks.

Comment: Berks does use the knife.rb, correct? If that is the case, I could add a statement in there to make the $SSL_CERT_DIR env variable set for each knife.rb.

Comment: Yep, `ENV['SSL_CERT_DIR'] = ...`. That's what I've done in the past.

Comment: I added `ENV['SSL_CERT_DIR'] = "#{certs_loc}/trusted_certs/chefserverurl.localnet.net.crt"` However, its still not picking it up.

Comment: Because `_DIR` is for a directory, and you are specifying a single file. Use `_FILE` for that.

Comment: I receive the same error when I remove the file name and leave it just the directory `"#{certs_loc}/trusted_certs"`

Comment: I'll try the FILE option this time